# Capture warning message in R library from Python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I would like to capture warning message in R and stored as a string in Python.  My problem started from a sample data of disease in pandas dataframe as follows:

```
dates = ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05",
         "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-10"]

cases = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, "cases": cases})
```

To estimate the reproduction number of that disease, I save that pandas dataframe into a csv file then use R library called EpiEstim.  My R code look like this.

```
library(EpiEstim)
disease <- read.csv(file="df.csv")
res_parametric_si <- estimate_R(disease$cases, 
                                method="parametric_si",
                                config=make_config(list(mean_si=5, std_si=1)))
```

Since the number of cases is very rare in daily.  There is a warning message from EpiEstim as follows:

```
Default config will estimate R on weekly sliding windows.
    To change this change the t_start and t_end arguments. 
Warning message:
In estimate_R_func(incid = incid, method = method, si_sample = si_sample,  :
  You're estimating R too
```

Since my data pipeline is Python environment, I called EpiEstim from Python using rpy2.  My code looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()

dates = ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05",
         "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-10"]

cases = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, "cases": cases})

eps = importr("EpiEstim")
rdf = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
results = eps.estimate_R(rdf[1], method="parametric_si", config=eps.make_config(mean_si=5, std_si=1))
results = dict(results.items())
rhat = pandas2ri.ri2py(results["R"])
```

Everything works well except I could not capture warning message occurred in R environment.  May I have your suggestions to solve this problem?  I really need to capture such warning messages.  Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried `eps.warnings()`?

Comment: Hi duckmayr, i did.  It showed AttributeError: module 'EpiEstim' has no attribute 'warnings'

Comment: Ah, sorry :(     I know that works in some contexts, so it was worth a shot